# JavaScript to C++ conversion: error with the % operator

Tags: c++

JavaScript:

```
var lon2 = (lon1.toRad()+L+3*Math.PI)%(2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;
```

I have converted to c++:

```
double lon2 = (Deg2Rad(lon1)+L+3*PI)%(2*PI) - PI;
```

Note: Deg2Rad func returns double, PI is a double also, L and lon1 also double. Then I got the following errors for the same line:

```
error C2296: '%' : illegal, left operand has type 'double'
error C2297: '%' : illegal, right operand has type 'double'
```

Whats wrong with this `%` modulo?

Comment: Do not spam exclamation marks.

Answer (score 6):

the modulo operator is not defined for `float`s and `double`s (only integer types), use [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/) instead (or consider changing how you perform your calculation).

Comment: Indeed, the JavaScript spec specifically says that its `%` implementation is more similar to `fmod` than `%` [Section 11.5.3](http://es5.github.com/#x11.5.3)

Answer (score 4):

C++ will not perform a modulo operation on a `double` - I suggest using `fmod()` in `<math.h>`

If you wanted to be very fancy about it, you could overload the modulo (`%`) operator to handle your desired datatypes.

Answer (score 2):

`%` is defined for integers only.  Use the [fmod()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/fmod/) function in `<cmath>` to calculate the modulus of a floating point number (`float` or `double`).